# Symfony onAuthenticationSuccess did not redirect to the right page

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-security

I've set the security on one of my websites, by using [Symfony security](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#b-authenticating-your-users).

My users can only access websites if they are fully logged in.
Each user can be a client or an admin.

So in my LoginFormAuthenticator I've set the redirect as following :

```
    public function onAuthenticationSuccess(Request $request, TokenInterface $token, $providerKey)
    {

        $user = $token->getUser();
        if ($targetPath = $this->getTargetPath($request->getSession(), $providerKey)) {
            if($user instanceof Employe) {
                return new RedirectResponse($this->urlGenerator->generate('Admin'));
            } else if($user instanceof Client){
                return new RedirectResponse($this->urlGenerator->generate('AccueilClient'));
            }
        }else{
            return new RedirectResponse($this->urlGenerator->generate('app_login'));
        }

    }
```

And the login form looks like this :

```
<form method="post">
                            <img class="responsive-img"
                                 src="{{ asset('build/assets/images/Logo_resized.[hash8].jpg') }}">

                            {% if error %}
                                <div class="row">

                                    <div class="card red">
                                        <div class="card-content black-text">
                                            <span class="card-content">{{ error.messageKey|trans(error.messageData, 'security') }}</span>
                                        </div>

                                    </div>

                                </div>
                            {% endif %}

                            {% if app.user %}
                                <div class="row">

                                    <div class="card red">
                                        <div class="card-content blue accent-1">
                                            <span class="card-content"> Vous êtes déjà connecté en tant que : {{ app.user.nom }} {{ app.user.prenom }},
                                                <a class="black-text" href="{{ path('redirect') }}">Accéder au site</a></span>
                                        </div>

                                    </div>

                                </div>
                            {% endif %}


                            <label for="inputEmail">Email</label>
                            <input type="email" value="{{ last_username }}" name="email" id="inputEmail"
                                   class="form-control" required autofocus>
                            <label for="inputPassword">Mot de passe</label>
                            <input type="password" name="password" id="inputPassword" class="form-control" required>

                            <input type="hidden" name="_csrf_token"
                                   value="{{ csrf_token('authenticate') }}"
                            >

                            <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary blue_SPIE" type="submit">
                                Se connecter
                            </button>
                        </form>
```

But every time, I've tried to log in. I'm always redirect on the `app_login` page and not on the `Admin` or `AccueilClient`. I have no idea why I'm not redirect as I want on the good page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$targetPath = $this->getTargetPath($request->getSession(), $providerKey)` condition is to redirect back the user if they call a restricted route before.
Therefore the user wont be check.

```php
public function onAuthenticationSuccess(Request $request, TokenInterface $token, $providerKey)
{
    $user = $token->getUser();
    if ($targetPath = $this->getTargetPath($request->getSession(), $providerKey)) {
        return new RedirectResponse($targetPath);
    }

    if ($user instanceof Employe) {
        return new RedirectResponse($this->urlGenerator->generate('Admin'));
    }

    if($user instanceof Client) {
        return new RedirectResponse($this->urlGenerator->generate('AccueilClient'));
    }
        
    return new RedirectResponse($this->urlGenerator->generate('app_login'));
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much I understand now. Thank you very much.